# Parsing ? in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to parse using htaccess

```
abc.com/a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d
```

(here everything after
 ? are random)

to

```
abc.com/index.php?q=
```

Means

```
a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d should go into index.php?q=
```

Here the problem is ? and & are not able to receive by PHP file

Value till a/b/c/ is received.

I want to convert:

```
abc.com/a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d
```

to

```
abc.com/index.php?q=a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d
```

How to first encode "?" and "&" to %3f and %26 respectively?

How to receive

```
a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d
```

in index.php?q=

I'm using this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

But this is not able to transfer ? and & in PHP file !

Comment: Your rule doesn’t do the rewrite you want in the first place. You are matching the `a/b/c/` part, and specify that as the value for the `q` parameter. The original query string gets joined with that, so what you are rewriting to is `index.php?q=a/b/c/&target=dd&a=b&c=d`

Comment: How to get "a/b/c/&target=dd&a=b&c=d" in q= ?

Comment: You’ll have to append that after the $1 yourself, the value can be found in the server variable `QUERY_STRING`

Comment: @misorude `QSA` does that for you already.

Comment: @user2890725 What exactly happens on the browser when you make this request?

Comment: @vivek_23 if they wanted a “normal” query string in the result, yes. But they don’t want `target` as a second parameter, they want a `?` in the place where you’d normally expect a `&`. They want one single parameter `q`, with the value `a/b/c/?target=dd&a=b&c=d`

Comment: You’re probably gonna need the `B` flag for proper escaping of the special characters. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: @misorude Ok, I misread the question. Now, it seems even `{REQUEST_URI}` has a role to play.

Comment: Why do you ask the question _twice_ ? Please note that this is considered bad behavior here on SO.